# Berkovich Analytification of the transseries

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology, nonstandard-analysis

I am looking for references to articles about the following subjects:

- Connections from the field of (real) transseries to the field of surreal numbers (mentioned very briefly in the introduction of Joris v.d. Hoeven's thesis).
- Description of the non-Archimedean geometry of transseries, in particular: What do you get when you take the (Berkovich) Analytification of the transseries.

Comment: "All a mathematician needs to know in order to apply transseries"

http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4877

Comment: Yeah, it's an intricate and inspiring read, and so is Joris's thesis. But (aside from some remarks in the margins), it doesn't tell me much about its non-Archimedean topology (aside from the obvious order valuation)